# Saving checkbox data as json

Tags: laravel

I have 3 checkboxes, and i would like to store their information in DB. I think that JSON could be best situation for this, because i need to retrieve checkbox data for update view, so that they would show information as it was inserted.

I only cant figure out how to do it. 
How can i pass all checkbox data to controller store it as json ans save in DB?

`{{Form::label('user_photo', 'Valodas',['class' => 'control-label'])}}
                Latviešu {{Form::checkbox('val[0]', 'Latviesu',false)}}
                Angļu {{Form::checkbox('val[1]', 'Anglu',false)}}
                Krievu {{Form::checkbox('val[2]', 'Krievu',false)}}`

Only thing i have in controller ir this - `$valoda =  $req->input('val');` so that i could see data, but it only shows me this

[image]

There in no 1, or 0 that would show if checkbo is checked or not. Dont know where to go from here.

Comment: when it's checked it exist in input, when it's not checked it will not. So if You've 4 checkboxes and You've checked 2 of them You'll get that 2 checkboxed values in handler (action) code. So better keep that checkboxed data in somewhere as constant or in db and then compare that info in action.

Comment: How can i store that data as JSON? or you would prefer better tactic to save that data in DB? Because i will save that information in DB and then i will get it from there

Comment: I recommend You to have a table where You'll insert them one by line